# AngularJS e backend Java

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jax-rs

Olá,

Estou deixando de utilizar o framework JSF para iniciar a utilização de AngularJS. Gostaria de saber se alguém possuí um exemplo de integração entre o AngularJS com Back-end Java, para que eu possa ver o funcionamento da passagem de parâmetro do Front-end para o Back-end e a gravação no banco de dados MySql. Pode ser exemplo de um crud qualquer ou login com Spring ou Jax-RS, pesquisei na internet mas a maioria dos exemplos são muito extensos, confusos ou está faltando classe.

Alguém possuí um código no github para entendimento de processo entre o AngularJS e o Back-end?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: da uma olhada http://uaihebert.com/aplicacao-web-completa-angular-twitter-bootstrap-spring-mvc-data-e-security/  bem completo

Comment: Se está começando agora sugiro usar o Angular2 com uma api REST no backEnd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse [guia](http://www.java2blog.com/2016/08/spring-mvc-angularjs-example.html) é bem simples e explicativo pra mostrar o Spring MVC com o AngularJS, porém ele não tem a conexão com o banco.

Esse [guia](http://www.programming-free.com/2014/07/spring-data-rest-with-angularjs-crud.html) possui conexão com o banco, mas é um pouco menos explicativo na parte do Angular, mas junto com o guia anterior acredito que é um bom kick-off.

Este outro [guia](https://dzone.com/articles/crud-using-spring-mvc-40) também é bem legal, não é tão simples mas ta bem bacana. Ele usa o MySql, Angular e o Spring MVC.

Comment: Beleza, eu tinha visto o uaihebert que o Otto aconselhou acima mas achei meio confuso, mas com os 2 primeiros links da sua resposta descritos aqui ficou mais claro a compreensão do processo. Valeu gente.